# PyCharm: Cannot find reference 'Gtk' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pygobject

I have a clean virtual environment

```
conda create --name gtk python=3.8

conda install -c conda-forge pygobject gtk3
```

When I add the import `from gi.repository import Gtk` according to the [PyGTK3](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) wiki.

PyCharm complains saying `Cannot find reference 'Gtk' in '__init__.py'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyCharm provides an auto-fix `'Generate stubs for binary module'` which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in a project I'm working on and I solved it like this:

Create a new environment variable with the name: `PYTHONPATH` and the value: *address of your project folder*

After that, open cmd and type the command:

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%
```

It will return the path entered as a value if the variable is correct.

Close and reopen PyCharm and the problem will be fixed in a few seconds.

Hope it helps - Luis Fernando M. Bezerra from Brazil